# discord.js-commando Announce command

Tags: discord.js

I'm having some slight issues with my announce.js command.

I've already tried a few different things but am generally new to commando.

Here is what I currently have.

`Announce.js`

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const Commando = require('discord.js-commando');

module.exports = class AnnounceCommand extends Commando.Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'announce',
      aliases: ['ann'],
      group: 'moderation',
      memberName: 'announce',
      userPermissions: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES', 'MANAGE_CHANNELS'],
      description: 'Send an announcement to the specified channel',
      examples: ['announce Hello, world!'],
      args: [
        {
          key: 'text',
          prompt: 'What would you like the bot to announce?',
          type: 'string',
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  run(msg, { text }) {
    let channel = msg.mentions.channels.first();
    if (!channel) return;
    const embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
      .setAuthor(`Megumin`, `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/735785909420556370/3db81cc7fb540907d7a147fb87118217.png?size=2048`)
      .setThumbnail(`https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/735785909420556370/3db81cc7fb540907d7a147fb87118217.png?size=2048`)
      .setColor(0xffcc00)
      .addField(`Announcement`, (text), false)
      .setFooter(`Megumin`, `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/735785909420556370/3db81cc7fb540907d7a147fb87118217.png?size=2048`)
      .setTimestamp();
    return channel.send(embed);
  }
};
```

Right now it is sending the announcement to the specified channel, however it has two slight issues.

1. It won't send it to announcement channels
2. It mentions the channel in the message.

I would much appreciate it if someone could explain to me how it is that I would go about fixing those two issues.

This is my `index.js` if it helps:

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js-commando');
const path = require('path');
const {token, owner_id, prefix} = require("./config.json");

const client = new Client({
    commandPrefix: prefix,
    owner: owner_id,
    invite: 'https://discord.io/NewHorizonDevelopment',
})

client.registry
    .registerDefaultTypes()
    .registerGroups([
        ['misc', 'Misc'],
        ['moderation', 'Moderation'],
        ['fun', 'Fun']
    ])
    .registerDefaultGroups()
    .registerDefaultCommands()
    .registerCommandsIn(path.join(__dirname, 'commands'))

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}(${client.user.id})`)
    client.user.setActivity(`${prefix}help`, {
        type: "STREAMING",
        url: "https://www.twitch.tv/discord"
    });
})

client.on('guildMemberAdd', (guildMember) => {
    guildMember.addRole(guildMember.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Member"));
});

client.on('error', console.error)


client.login(token)
```

I'm running off `node.js 12.x` and using `discord.js-commando` if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after coming back to this, some time later i might add, I finally managed to get it fixed in exactly the way I was originally going for.

Here is my working code for those who might want to try it for themselves:

`announce.js`

```js
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('../../config.json')

module.exports = class NewsCommand extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'announce',
            aliases: ['ann'],
            group: 'guild',
            memberName: 'announce',
            userPermissions: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES', 'MANAGE_CHANNELS'],
            description: 'Send an announcement to the specified channel',
            examples: [`${config.prefix}announce [channel.mention] [message]`],
            args: [
                {
                    key: 'text',
                    prompt: 'What would you like the bot to announce?',
                    type: 'string',
                },
            ],
        });
    }

    run(message) {
        if (message.author.bot) return;

        let text = message.content.split(" ");
        let args = text.slice(1);

        if (message.channel.type === "dm") return;

        let channel = message.mentions.channels.first();
        if (!channel) return;
        
        let announcement = args.slice(1).join(" ");

        let embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(this.client.user.username, this.client.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setThumbnail(this.client.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .addField(`Announcement`, announcement, false)
            .setFooter(this.client.user.username, this.client.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setTimestamp(new Date().toISOString())
        return channel.send(embed);
    }
};
```